# get products from multiple categories

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection, category-products

There is an array of category ids i.e. array(18,19,25);

I want to get those products which has all these categories from above array. Product should present in 18,19 and 25.

Array values can be anything i.e. category ids.

Comment: You mean that you want to get an array of products which exist in categorys 18, 19 AND 25? Or do you want to get them if they are in any of 18, 19 and 25?

Comment: That product should present in 18,19 and 25.

Comment: that means both 3 categories ? If  product is in one category then what will be happen.

Comment: Then that product should not be displayed. Product should present in all categories from the array

Comment: You should extend little bit product collection. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9474597/7395701)

Answer (score 1):

Let's Assume you have categoryIds Array

```
$categories = array(18,19,25);
```

First You have to do category join

```
$collection->joinField(
    'category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 
    'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left'
);
```

Now add simple `IN` condition of `collection`

```
$pCollection->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => implode(',', $categories)));
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('finset' => '18','19','25')));
```

Comment: please join with category product table.. you may be miss it

Comment: Can you give me entire query.. @amit bera

Comment: This produces an `uncaught Mage_Eav_Exception: Invalid attribute name: category_id`

Answer (score 0):

This can be a bit scary but is working fine for me, with:

- Magento 1.9
- Flat Table

```
// An array of category ids
$categoryIds = [18,19,25];

// Get a collection of products
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

// Add a filter for each category: only products belonging to each
// category will be in the collection
$i = 1;
foreach ($categoryIds as $categoyId) {
  $collection->joinField(
    "category_product_${i}",
    'catalog/category_product', 
    null, 
    'product_id=entity_id',
    "{{table}}.category_id=${categoyId}", 
    'inner'
  );
  $i++;
}

// Set distinct (avoid duplicate products)
$collection->distinct(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it

```
$catIds = array('10','82');
$productCollection = 
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->setStoreId(0)
->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 
'product_id=entity_id', null, 'left')
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' =>  array('finset' =>
$catIds )))
->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$productCollection->getSelect()->group('product_id')->distinct(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
foreach($category_ids as $id)
    $products->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id));
```

**UPDATE**: this answer is wrong - it will filter the collection by the last category from `$category_ids` array - `addCategoryFilter` method doesn't support stacking. I didn't know that - what is the point of making a filter that supports only one category?

Comment: This loads products with an **OR** logic (products in a category **or** in a another category), but the question was about load product with an **AND** logic

Comment: @Andrea we are both wrong. addCategoryFilter when applied multiple times takes into account only the last category. so my code will filter by the last category id in $category_ids.

Comment: Ah, ok, I didn't know it :) I found a way to do this by building a query with multiple joins. I added an answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
              ->getCollection()
              ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
              ->load();
   foreach ($collection as $product){
       echo $product->getId().'</br>';
       echo $product->getName().'</br>';
   }
```